# Movie about a demon-posessed box

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This movie was released somewhere in the 90s to 99, I cannot remember most of the scenes because I was 8 back then, but I do remember a bit of the plot.

- A number of shipyard crews discovered an item that looked like a box (approximately the size of a treasure chest) and they placed the box on a ship.
- Horrifying things happen when they open it or unseal the box. Seems there is a demonic force that starts to attack them.
- Around 6-7 or more FBI or secret service agents are shooting at a few number of moving Medieval period or Samurai period armors in a museum.
- However, all, or some of the agents got slain.

Comment: Sounds very much like [The Mummy (1999)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120616/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

Comment: It is not. The setting of the story is in a present timeline

Comment: Hellraiser? Magic evil box

Comment: How big was the box? Was it comparable in size to a Rubik's Cube, or something more along the lines of a treasure chest?

Comment: @Valorum I doubt its Hellraiser. The box is quite big.

Comment: @LogicDictates The size of the box is around the size of a treasure chest. But bigger

Comment: Has some points in common with [_The Relic (1997)_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120004).  But not a perfect match.

Comment: You may want to investigate "alone in the dark" from 2005, with Christian Slater. A very awful movie. It has a ship, and some ancient artifacts that make a door to a monster dimension.

Comment: I want to watch this movie. Sounds like a cross between Night at the Museum and Indiana Jones: Raiders of the Lost Ark

Answer (score 3):

It kind of sounds like the Wish Master 1.
A evil Genni who is a statue and is being taken in ship,  the box falls and a Ruby gem is taken and is later released. A evil Djinn is released and a cop/agent and the a lady are trying to tie the clues.  There is a scene with a museum and many people died as they watched evil stuff.[image]

Comment: The description of the agents being killed by the animated armors reminded me of that scene from _Wishmaster_, but there isn't really any focus on a box in that film. Sure, the statue with the gem containing the Djinn does initially arrive in a large crate, but we never see it being placed on the ship as mentioned in the description, nor do we see it being opened in the conventional sense (rather, we see it drop and smash apart). Also, the real focus is on the gem, not the crate.